# study orientation for ROBOT "GO TO SPECIFIED DESTINATION"

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm studying ROS, my goal is to build a robot that I can inform a target point on the RVIZ map (2d nav goal).
I would like to use the laser scan RPLIDAR A1, raspberrypi + PC and robot with two motorized wheels.

I already conclude the initial tutorials of WIKI-ROS (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) what would be the next studies that suggest me?

I do not know where to start.

Example:

1º tutorial WIKI-ROS -> 2º ........ -> 3º ........ -> 4º ........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312805/study-orientation-for-robot-%22go-to-specified-destination%22/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that the next set of tutorials for you to look at is for the navigation stack: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation. The navigation stack has very extensive tutorials and is made for navigating to a point specified by 2d nav goal. Reading all of the documentation on this will give you a much better understanding of tf_frames and other basics that are necessary for successful navigation.

---

Originally posted by [Joe Dyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/39484/joe-dyer/) with karma: 36 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1